# Difference between arbitary collection and finite collection

Tags: real-analysis

In basic topology of real number ( real analysis) , there is these two theorems which states : The union of arbitrary collection of open sets is open. Another one is : The intersection of finite collection of open sets is open. Here, I would like to ask what is the difference between arbitrary and finite ? If I change finite in the second theorem, will it still hold ? If it does not hold, can anyone give some examples to illustrate ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An arbitrary collection of open sets is just that: any collection of open sets at all, finite or infinite, with no restriction save that the sets be open. If you change *finite* to *arbitrary* in the second statement, it becomes false. For example, in $\Bbb R$ the sets $(-x,x)$ for $x>0$ are all open, but their intersection is $\{0\}$, which is not open: $\bigcap_{x>0}(-x,x)=\{0\}$. Here are two more examples.

- For each $q\in\Bbb Q$ let $U_q=\Bbb R\setminus\{q\}=(\leftarrow,q)\cup(q,\to)$; this is an open set. But $\bigcap_{q\in\Bbb Q}U_q=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, the set of irrational numbers, which is definitely not an open set.
- For each $n\ge 2$ let $U_n=\left(\frac1n,1+\frac1n\right)$; then $$\begin{align*}\bigcap_{n\ge 2}U_n&=\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)\cap\left(\frac13,\frac43\right)\cap\left(\frac14,\frac54\right)\cap\ldots\\
  &=\left(\frac12,1\right]\;.\end{align*}$$ You may have to think a bit about that intersection to see that it really is $\left(\frac12,1\right]$.

Comment: thx for your explanation and examples. I understand now

Comment: @Idonknow: You’re welcome; glad it helped.

Comment: Since set of irrational numbers is an open set, is the set of rational numbers  also an open set ?

Comment: @Idonknow: The set of irrational numbers is **not** an open set, and neither is the set of rational numbers. Neither of them even contains an open interval.